# i want to get the text of an entry called userE from super class loginform to compose email class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, inheritance, pycharm

this is my super class, removed unnecessary code

```py
class loginform:
    global username
    def __init__(self,root):
        #=====================================root=====================================
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('1350x700+100+50')
        self.root.configure(background= "orange")
        self.root.title("Bmail - login / Sign-in")


        self.userE = tk.Entry(master=frame, font=("Verdana, Bold", 11), bg="white", fg="grey", width=50)
        
        self.userE.place(x=90, y=355)
        passl = tk.Label(text="password:", master=frame, font=("Verdana, Bold", 11)).place(x=10, y=390)




    def access_func(self,event):
       compose_mail.acc
```

I want to access `self.userE.cget("text")`  but it gives me none, bound func error or goes into infinite loop

here is my composemail (child)class

```
   access = loginform
class compose_mail(access):
   def __init__(self, root):
    obj1=super().__init__(root)
    self.root = root
    self.root = Toplevel()
    self.root.title("Bmail-Compose Mail form")
    self.root.geometry("1350x700+100+50")
    self.root.resizable(False, False)
    self.root.configure(bg="orange")


    self.luser = Label(cframe, bg="yellow", width=50, text=self.acc)
    self.luser.place(x=20, y=650)
def acc(self):
    a=self.userE.cget("text")

root=tk.Tk()
obj=loginform(root)
obj.root.mainloop()
```

help me solve this issue please....

Comment: This is way too much code for us to debug. Please remove all of the unnecessary details.

Comment: removed unecessary code now . please help me sir

Comment: Instead of `self.userE.cget("text")` use `self.userE.get()`.

Comment: does not work , the data get deleted super().init() is loaded inside init of compose class @TheLizzard

Comment: Can you please edit your question with a complete minimal working example? What do you mean by the data is deleted when you use `super().__init__()`? Also [this](https://pastebin.com/jLr2dh2T) might help you